# What does breaking time translation symmetry mean? What's wrong with time crystal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, time-crystals

I was reading about a new state of matter which is called [time crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_crystal), this seemingly violates thermodynamic which had intrigue me. Someone told me that when you perform an experiment in the past, now or future the outcomes should be consistent every time, so how did time crystal blatantly go against this notion? How do they measure the periodic pattern in time instead of space(motion)? Can a single atom turns into time crystal or do you need a array of atoms in a form of lattice to do that?

Comment: Maybe start here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_crystal where it says symmetries give rise to conservation laws through Noether's theorm. Time translation symmetry gives energy conservation, a concept many of us are quite fond of.